# Even after setting 301 redirect, Google Search Console displays 301 redirect error

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

I want to change my web address to a different domain, and I have added 301 Redirect to my old site, but it still shows an error.

[image: 301 error]

Here is the screenshot of Vercel:
[image: Vercel]

and the CURL response is 301:
[image: CURL request]

What shall I do to fix this error?

Comment: I just checked, and everything is working fine.

Comment: Does the error still exist?

Answer (score 3):

It is actuelly not an error. You are trying to fetch a home page with a 301 redirect on it and Google is telling you that you can not fetch it because it doesn't exist anymore.
 You can now simply fetch the 301 targeted url (dlhairyashah.dev).
I checked your redirect and that works fine.

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

It is an error because Google very clearly instructs to initiate the 301 redirect from old site to new site, before attempting this verification. I agree it makes no sense as it's then trying to index a forwarded url...?

Comment: Can you please add a link to a google page that "very clearly instructs to initiate the 301 redirect from old site to new site"